# How to disable UISlider without making image gray

Tags: ios, user-interface

```
[_slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"disableImage"]  forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

The method does't make sense, because when i set `_slider.enable=NO;`
the `disableImage` become a little bit gray.

Is there any attribute just like `adjustsImageWhenDisabled` to forbid color fading？

Comment: use yourslider.alpha = 0;

Comment: just try to disable userInteractionEnabled

Answer (score 1):

The .enable property influence whether the button does anything or not.

You have several choices to disable/hide your UISlider.

You can :

- Use hidden to make it invisible
- Set the .alpha between 0.0 and 1.0
- Disable User Interaction

Comment: I just want the slider has different Thumb、TrackImage in UIControlStateNormal and UIControlStateDisabled status.  So i set two different image, however the "disableImage" become a little gray  in UIControlStateDisabled when i set .enable

Comment: [_slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wind_enable"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wind_disable"]  forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    _slider.enable=YES;

Comment: Disabling just user interaction worked for me.